# Custom Error Handling 404 CSS and JS not loaded Java EE

Tags: jsp, error-handling

I'm trying to customize the handling of 404 errors in my Java EE project. The css files are not getting loaded . Here is my web.xml file :
Note that I'm using the full path of my Jsp file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">


  <display-name>Dep_info</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/JSPs/home.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/JSPs/PageNotFound.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/JSPs/PageNotFound.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
        <location>/JSPs/PageNotFound.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

<!--   <filter> -->
<!--     <filter-name>CharacterSetFilter</filter-name> -->
<!--     <filter-class>com.CharacterSetFilter</filter-class> -->
<!-- </filter> -->

<!-- <filter-mapping> -->
<!--     <filter-name>CharacterSetFilter</filter-name> -->
<!--     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> -->
<!-- </filter-mapping> -->

</web-app>
```